# Is there a way to check controller parameters before the controller method?

Tags: symfony

My controller code has more lines to validate the received parameters than the real function code and I was wondering if there is a way to do this validations outside the controller method.

I have checked the Symfony docs but I could not found anything. I was thinking in something like a listener but just for that method.

Thank you guys.

EDIT: I'm aware about route requirements. I'm looking for a place to inject my own code.

EDIT: Added a little snippet.

```
public function searchAddressAction($radius, $page){

    if ($radius < 5 || $radius > 50) {

        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Radius not valid');
    }

    if ($page <= 0) {

        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Page not found');
    }
```

EDIT 3: This seems to be the way but I can't make it work (thanks to @dlondero):

```
search_address:
    path: /{address}/{radius}/{page}
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Default:searchAddress
        radius: 20
        page: 1
    options:
        expose: true
    requirements:
        radius: \d+
        page: \d+
    condition: 'request.get("radius") == 50 '
```

Comment: What kind of validation do you want to do on the parameters? And what should happen if it doesn't validate?

Comment: I want to check if the parameters are between two values for example. If not, the code will throw a not found exception.

Comment: Create private methods with the validations in your controller class and call them in the public methods (for example `indexAction` or `editAction`).

Comment: It would be also good, if you can provide a snippet of your code. Generally the validations should be done in the entities, but here it seems you have another requirements.

Comment: I thought about that, but I was hoping for a better way to do that. I don't want to do a validation method for each method.

Comment: Well then just extract the validation code to a private method and call it from the controller at the beginning.

Comment: What is the point in extract the validation code in a private method if you will only call that method once?

Comment: Looks like you're more worried of having more validation code than other code. Don't know if you want to use that in one place ore more.

Comment: Nope. I just want to keep clean the controller as much as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the default route requirements, there are 2 options to do some extra checks if a request should be passed through to a Controller.

1. Create a custom route loader.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html

This can be very useful if you want to get route requirements from the database for example.

2. Conditions (Might be what you're looking for)

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html

This is using the expression language https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html

I don't think you can use the parameters name in here, but you can access the query in the request, which would for sure meet the requirements of the path.

If both of these are not working, than the validation has to be done in the Controller.
You can of course create a class to do the validation, and in your controller you use that class so you only have to call 1 method to do the validation.

I don't recommend a listener for this, as it would be called for all requests, and then has to do a check if it should do the validation.
Besides that it's performance wise not preferable, it doesn't make sense to do this kind of validation in a listener, so if someone else would work on your code, he has to dig in weird places to find out why a controller returns a 404, but still matches the route.

Comment: Thanks, just right now I'm trying to make it work the conditions but even when the syntax is supposedly correct, it just don't work.

Comment: Seems like in the condition, the parameter bag is still empty. So you can't access to url parameters outside the controller unless you use a listener.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are looking for [kernel.request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request) event. Then you could have your listener/subscriber and check what you need to check.

Comment: I thought about that, but a kernel.request event will be triggered in every request and that will affect to the performance of the entire project .

Comment: Well you can return early for requests you don't need to check.

Comment: Yes. But I'm a little obsesed with the performance. That is the reason I discarded the idea and made this post. It's not a bad solution but I hope it's not the best.

Comment: This seems perfect but I can't make it work. I'll edit the question!

Comment: Performances will not be influenced, it's not the matter here. Just, using listeners to run fundamental security/consistency code is less explicit and, as @NicoKaag also mentioned, it will be difficult to debug & figure out for somebody that doesn't know the structure of the project already. Private controller methods or Route conditions, even if both with drawbacks, might be the more maintainable solutions.